# Coloring regex word patterns in JTextPane cannot color trailing delimiter

Tags: java, regex, jtextpane

I am almost there thanks to the good people on this list. I just need to please have help with the last bit.

I have a JTextPane where I match certain word patterns and change their color to red. Any word or phrase that starts with pipe/open square brace, and ends with close square brace/pipe, like |[this]|, is matched with the following regex `"(\\|\\[[^\\]]*\\])"`.

This works 99%, but it does not color the trailing | red. And if I try to include this in the regex, by adding a `\\|` to the end, it fails to match the anything.

Here's my code.

In the button that calls the class, I send a silly string for now that has the delimiters:

```
private void jButton13ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    JFrame Escapedframe = new JFrame("Skipppy Cars word changer");
    Escapedframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    JTextPane SkippytextPane = new JTextPane();
    SkippytextPane.setDocument(new ElementHighlight());
    SkippytextPane.setText("You should try the |[new model]| car, the |[Skippy 2000]|. The Skippy 2000 comes standard with all the |[features]| of the Bippy 3000, at half the price. You can buy one today at your |[athorized Skippy/Bippy]| dealer.");
    Escapedframe.add(SkippytextPane);

    Escapedframe.setSize(500,400);
    Escapedframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    Escapedframe.setVisible(true);

}
```

And then set:

```
private int pipeCharEnd (String Xtext, int index) {
    while (--index >= 0) {
        if (String.valueOf(Xtext.charAt(index)).matches("\\|")) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}

private int pipeCharStart (String Xtext, int index) {
    while (index < Xtext.length()) {
        if (String.valueOf(Xtext.charAt(index)).matches("\\|")) {
            break;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return index;
}
```

And finally the class:

```
class ElementHighlight extends DefaultStyledDocument {
  private final  MutableAttributeSet XRED = new SimpleAttributeSet();
  final StyleContext myProtected = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
  final AttributeSet attR = myProtected.addAttribute(myProtected.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.RED);
  final AttributeSet attB = myProtected.addAttribute(myProtected.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.BLUE);

@Override
  public void insertString (int offset, String Pstr, AttributeSet RedBlue) throws BadLocationException
  {
   super.insertString(offset, Pstr, RedBlue);
   String text = getText(0, getLength());
   int pre = pipeCharEnd(text, offset);
   if (pre < 0) pre = 0;
   int post = pipeCharStart(text, offset + Pstr.length());
   int prewords = pre;
   int postwords = pre;

   while (postwords <= post) {
                if (postwords == post || String.valueOf(text.charAt(postwords)).matches("\\|")) {
                    if (text.substring(prewords, postwords).matches("(\\|\\[[^\\]]*\\])"))
                        setCharacterAttributes(prewords, postwords - prewords, attR, false);
                    else
                        setCharacterAttributes(prewords, postwords - prewords, attB, false);
                    prewords = postwords;
                }
                postwords++;
            }


  }


 }
```

Every delimited phrase is turning red, just as expected, except for the trailing pipe in each case, which remains blue.

As I said, I've gotten this far with the help of the good people on this list. If somebody could teach me how to colorize the trailing pipe in the delimiter, I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you enter the following `if` condition:

```
text.substring(prewords, postwords).matches("(\\|\\[[^\\]]*\\])")
```

... it means that the sub `String` between the indices `prewords` and `postword -1` (included) matches `(\\|\\[[^\\]]*\\])`. This **regex** looks for:

- a `|` followed by
- a `[` followed by
- a sequence of any characters except `]` followed by
- a `]`.

So, considering this sample `String`:

```
0123|[6789012345678]|12345
```

The **regex** would match `|[6789012345678]` (and not the trailing `|`). Thus, we would enter the `if` condition with `prewords` valued at `4` and `postwords` set to `20`.

```
prewords = 4, postwords = 20
    v               v
0123|[6789012345678]|12345
```

If you do:

```
setCharacterAttributes(prewords, postwords - prewords, attR, false);
```

... then you're declaring that:

- `postwords - prewords` characters
- starting from index `prewords`
- will be **red**.

... which is `20-4` (16) characters from index `4`, which in our sample `String` represents the following sub `String`: `|[6789012345678]` (only 16 characters).

If you want to also set the colour of one more character... simply add `+1` to your method call!

*i.e.:*

```
//                                                   here
//                                                     v
setCharacterAttributes(prewords, postwords - prewords +1, attR, false);
```

Comment: I must stay, I had to read this twice. Not that it was in any way difficult to understand. I had to read it twice because I marveled at how rich, detailed, precise, and perfect the answer was. You went above and beyond in providing all the details. Your answer fixed my problem perfectly, but more important, in a way that taught me. Sincere thanks to you @ccjmne!